# Create union of buffers in PostGIS visible in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, buffer

I would like to merge overlapping buffers created in PostGIS and have as many polygons as there are not overlapping merged buffers, that can be viewed in QGIS.
The answer of [Creating dissolved buffers in QGIS using PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144030/how-to-create-dissolved-buffers-in-qgis-with-postgresql-postgis/387355#387355) seems to be on the right path, but I do not understand what `g` is in the query:

```
CREATE VIEW buffer40units AS 

SELECT 
   g.path[1] as gid, 
   g.geom::geometry(Polygon, 31492) as geom 

FROM
   (SELECT 
     (ST_Dump(ST_UNION(ST_Buffer(geom, 40)))).* 
   FROM point
) as g;
```

Comment: By merge you mean union/dissolve? Can you add a screenshot?

Answer (score 3):

g refers to the sub-query:

```
(SELECT 
     (ST_Dump(ST_UNION(ST_Buffer(geom, 40)))).* 
   FROM point
)
```

point in that is the input layer, that is being buffered.